# Titanium Studio - Cannot change the button text of my Tabs on Android devices

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I have implemented my own manual method of switching the app's localization within the application without having to modify the device's localization settings. The user either clicks on a tabbed bar via a set of right nav buttons on iOS devices, or use the native menu on Android devices to select the desired language.

This method works great on iOS devices. It ***almost*** works great on Android devices in that all text labels are immediately set to the respective language after the user makes their selection. However, the native TabGroup tab titles are not changing on my Android devices. They change immediately on my iOS devices.

I've tried many different methods to try and work around this. I tried removing the existing tabs from the TabGroup, but Android doesn't support this, at least not while using Titanium. I tried closing the tabGroup then re-opening it, but this just causes my app to lock up. I also tried looping through all my tabs and setting the titles that way to no avail. I also attempted to use the splice() command on the tabs array of the tabGroup, and that just throws a TypeError complaining about not finding a default value for object.

This is becoming very frustrating. I've looked at custom tab options available, including the Titanium Marketplace module called Tabulous. I've not been thrilled with any of those alternatives, particularly with their poor horizontal layout performance or reliance on using images instead of a mix of images and text.

One thing I do know is that on Android devices, my tab titles are being changed, because, within my event listener where I set the tab titles on language selection, I can loop through the tabs in my tabGroup collection and output the titles which reflect the chosen language. However, Android for some reason does not redraw the tabs to show the new text.

Here's a snippet of my event listener where I set the tab titles:

```
Titanium.App.addEventListener('langChanged', function() {
    homeTab.title = al.L('home_win_title');
    servicesTab.title = al.L('services_win_title');
    mediaTab.title = al.L('media_win_title');
    contactTab.title = al.L('media_win_title');

    // Android test:
    if (Ti.Platform.name == 'android') {
        for (var t in tabGroup.tabs) {
            // The alert below returns the expected title based on the language selection!
            alert(tabGroup.tabs[t].title);
        }
    }
});
```

As I said, on my test iOS devices, the tab titles are updated as expected. On Android devices, they do not change (are not re-drawn), though the alerts I throw in the above loop show the correct text.

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue while also trying to support multiple languages in an app, and [this post on the Appcelerator Q&A site](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/69931/change-tab-title-on-android) appears to confirm that it's not possible to change the tab title on Android.

However I got around this problem by closing the tab group and opening a new one - so it is possible to do that, and it may be that you need to refactor some of your app to prevent the locking issue you mention.

Comment: Craig, thanks for the information. I'm glad to hear that you were able to get it to work by closing the tab group and opening a new one. Did you have different tab groups per each language, or did you just close/re-open the same tab group? In my app, I've defined and created the tab group within my app.js file and each tab opens a new window. Is this how your application is also structured, or do you possibly define your tab groups somewhere else? Just curious how you got it to work without locking up your application. BTW, the code snippet above resides within my app.js file also.

Comment: I use the same group for each language, but the locale strings are retrieved from a locale object that is injected into the tab group - so I close the existing one, switch a flag in the locale object so it serves up strings for the correct locale, then open a new one. I'm using the CommonJS approach that Appcelerator have been touting recently, so my tabgroup is created from a constructor function in a module; my app.js includes the module and creates it from there. A listener in app.js tied to a global App:locale:changed event triggers the closing/opening of the tab group.

Comment: It sounds like, as far as the tab group, you are handling the locale similarly to how I am. The difference seems to be in how you use the CommonJS approach to creating your tabgroup from a constructor function in a module. I also have a custom listener in my app.js file that I manually fire from my locale changing function that closes and re-opens the tab group after changing the tab text. So, it's great that it is doable, but perhaps the feasibility comes down to how my app is structured as you said. My tab group references *.js files when opening new windows for each link. Potential issue?

Comment: Ah, possibly - if you mean that you're using the 'url' parameter of the window, I've seen recently (I think it was in videos from an Appcelerator conference) that using different execution contexts in that fashion isn't recommended, which is why I'm using the Common JS approach. I'm still not 100% happy with the tabgroup open/close process; it does work but when repeated a few times the animations get a little crazy.

Comment: The other thing you could check for is that your event listener isn't continuously firing, and repeatedly opening/closing the tabgroup - I ran into that at first, and had to remove the event listener accordingly. It'll depend on your implementation of course, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I worked all last night refactoring my app to use the CommonJS approach... not an easy task! The closing/re-opening of tabs is working now, but once that happens, the application loses all references to my windows and modules (those that I've added via the 'requires' method). It complains about null pointers and whatnot. I did see that there's a JIRA ticket (http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-6144) that's been added to be able to change the tab labels on Android devices. If people start putting a watch on it, hopefully they'll prioritize the fix. I think I'm getting there.

Comment: Cool, I'm watching it now. Silly that we have to go through all this just to get around that little limitation! Yeah, the CommonJS approach is a lot different, if you haven't gone that way from the start it's probably a headache. I hope whatever way you end up doing it everything works out :)